# Join two identical tables on rows with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two identical tables, one with current values for rows, and one with new values.  I am trying to select only the rows from the new values table where any column in the new values table has a different value than the column in the old values table.  The query I am using now looks like:

```
SELECT `new`.`item_id` 
  FROM `new_items` AS `new` 
  JOIN `items`  AS `old` 
 WHERE new.item_id = old.item_id
   AND (new.price != old.price || 
        new.description != old.description || 
        new.description_long != old.description_long || 
        new.image_small != old.image_small || 
        new.image_large != old.image_large || 
        new.image_logo1 != old.image_logo1 )
```

However, this query takes WAY too long to execute.  Does MySQL have a better way to do this or does anyone know a more efficient query?

Comment: If your data is too large for this type of operations than instead of using query use procedure. But for that you have to burn your oil.

Comment: How many rows in each table? What are the index definitions?

Comment: approx 12,000 rows per table no indexes, should i add an index to each of these fields?

Comment: You should have an index on the item_id.    If "image_large" is really a large image, no wonder the query is slow.  Consider storing a hash of any large field for comparison purposes.  Do not add indexes on the other fields.

Comment: the images are just varchars with image url's and item_id is not the primary key, its a varchar sku, product_id is the primary key and there is an index on it.  Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: If you don't have an index on item_id then this query will do a full table scan on both tables just to match up the rows.  Try adding indexes on item_id.  If it's an SKU it should be unique.

Comment: oh yea that worked, make that comment an answer and i will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT n.item_id
  FROM NEW_ITEMS n
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM OLD_ITEMS o
                WHERE o.item_id = n.item_id
                  AND (o.price <> n.price
                   OR o.description <> n.description 
                   OR o.description_long <> n.description_long 
                   OR o.image_small <> n.image_small 
                   OR o.image_large <> n.image_large 
                   OR o.image_logo1 <> n.image_logo1))
```

Index all of the columns being compared.

Comment: hmm, i was gonna test this to see if it was faster than mine, but i keep getting an sql error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10' the error is somewhere near the AND but i cant figure out whats wrong with this query

Comment: @Chris: Try now - it was missing a bracket

Comment: Identical speed to mine, but this also works.  Any advantages to this?

Comment: @Chris: This won't produce duplicates if there's more than one old record that doesn't match -- it's likely adding DISTINCT/GROUP BY to your query will impact performance.  You also haven't mentioned if you added indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If the item_id (sku) is fairly unique (not with many duplicates item_id in the tables), then you will see big performance improvement by just adding an index on item_id.